# warning: class 'CardController' does not implement the 'UIGestureRecognizerDelegate' protocol

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

In my app i am trying to detect swipe gesture to navigate to the next page ...

Please find my below code below

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRightAction:)];
swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
swipeRight.delegate = self;
[cardsGridView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
```

when i run my application, i get the below warning...

```
warning: class 'MyGesture' does not implement the 'UIGestureRecognizerDelegate' protocol
```

Kindly help me up that what i am missing here.

UPDATE1 : can anybody pls show me a working code to detect the swipe....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol only defines optional methods. There are now two ways to get rid of the warning:

1. Do not set the delegate at all if you do not need any of those optional delegate methods. Your `swipeRightAction` method call will work anyway as you specify the target and the selector in the initializer.
2. If you need to set the delegate, indicate in the header file of your delegate class that the class implements the protocol by specifying it in angle brackets after your superclass name:

   `@interface YourClass : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> {
       ...
   }`

Edit: Thanks, I forgot to escape the angle brackets.

Comment: To clarify: `@interface CardController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegare> { ...`